# Integrating ogre3d with hololens

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11, ogre, hololens

I would like to integrate ogre3d with directx and c++ using hololens.

is it that possible to do so ?

what are the steps to convert the rendering engine, what's rendered to the frame buffer to the hololens buffer?

Comment: why negating my question without a feedback ?!

Comment: You would need a UWP application (Universal Windows Platform or, otherwise said, an application for the Windows Store using Windows 10 SDK) to deploy on the Hololens. Ogred3D would need to generate binaries of itself for UWP in order to work which I doubt. I don't really know Ogre3D but Unity does the trick for itself.

Answer (score 1):

As RCYR mentioned, to run on the Hololens you are currently required to use UWP.

## Running Ogre in an UWP app

There is a [wiki entry](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=Creating%20a%20Windows%20Store%20App%20using%20OGRE) which shows how to get an OGRE app running in UWP. First you can try to build a simple UWP app without any calls to the Hololens api at all. Note that you can run usual 2d- UWP apps which are not only made for hololens on the device in a windowed view (see [mixed reality documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/app_model#creating_an_immersive_view) for more detailes about 2d-views vs. immersive views).

You can check your UWP app by using the [Hololens-Emulator](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/using_the_hololens_emulator). It is integrated with visual studio.

[image]

If you just wanted to create a windowed app running on the Hololens you are done by now.

## Setting up an immersive view

But more likely you wanted to create an immersive view to display holograms. There are really helpful samples available at the [UWP samples repository](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples). I would recommend you look at the [HolographicSpatialMapping sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/HolographicSpatialMapping).

Basically the sample shows how to:

- create a [HolographicSpace](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/getting_a_holographicspace) (core class for immersive views)
- initalize direct3d device (can be done by Ogre as long as the adapter supports Hololens)
- register to camera added/ remove events and create resources (buffers and views) for each camera
- use the SpatialCoordinateSystem and locate the viewer
- get a HolographicFrame, render some content and present

There is a lot of basic functions that you can just copy&paste in the CameraResources and DeviceResources classes in the sample.

For development you should use the Hololens Emulator (mentioned above) and the [Visual Studio Graphics Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hh315751.aspx) which is fully supported with the Hololens Emulator such that you can easily debug what is going on in direct3d.